# Error connecting my instance using Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Im´m trying to connect my instance using cloud shell, but I have this error message:
marga_rosado@definitivo-152612:~$gcloud beta sql connect myinstance2 --user=root
Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 1 minute...done.
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'35.187.15.76' (using password: YES)

I don´t know how to solve this, I have the user root which allow any host, what can I do?

REgards

Comment: Without knowing your database specific settings, it's hard to know what the problem is. I suggest you to create a brand new v2 instance and connect it through cloud shell (the password is empty): https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#connect_to_your_instance_using_the_mysql_client_in_the_cloud_shell. Then, you can start to reproduce your issue from that instance.

Comment: Thank you for your ansewer, the problem is that I nedde a firs generation instance, as I´m going to use it in the App Maker, and it doesn´t support the second generation instance.

Comment: In v1, there is no entries that allow for any hosts (e.g. the cloud shell host) to connect to it as root. You should go to "access control" of the instance, add a user that allows for any hosts, before connecting to it through cloud shell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have created the user before trying to connect it, but I have the problem I reported.

Comment: Does it work if you create a brand new v1 instance?

Comment: No, it doesn´t work..